# How can I use custom formula among unique ones in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| NAME | POINT A |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | 98 |
| JOHN | 0 |
| HARRY | 115 |
| HARRY | 75 |

Group the unique ones in the name column. If one of these values ​​has a zero, write a zero. If it is not zero, I want to sum the values, how can I do it?

I want to get the output as the result of the above table like this

| NAME | POINT A |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN | 0 |
| HARRY | 190 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),
       {Σ,index(if(countifs(A:A,Σ,B:B,0)>0,0,sumif(A:A,Σ,B:B)))})
```

[image]

***formula (`semicolon convention`)***

```js
=let(Σ;unique(tocol(A2:A;1));
       {Σ\index(if(countifs(A:A;Σ;B:B;0)>0;0;sumif(A:A;Σ;B:B)))})
```

Comment: OMG I never knew that `toCol(` method to ignore blanks. *Gone are my days of using Filter!* Very cool.